# Nativescript + Angular Setup

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

upon running tns run android --emulator I get the following error

Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2
node_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-providers.d.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame'.

**Dependencies:**
tns-android: **3.2.0** 
nativescript-angular: **^4.2.0**
nativescript-theme-core: **~1.0.4**
nativescript-dev-typescript: **~0.5.0**
typescript: **~2.4.2**

It launches my android emulator, and then upon tns installing... It displays this error. I copied the starter angular project from Nativescripts website.

Comment: SOLVED: npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save

Comment: Instead of writing a comment, answer your question with an description how you solved the issue by yourself to mark the question as answered :)